# Is $B^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}$ always a subobject of $Z^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}$?

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I'm reading about spectral sequences from various places (e.g. "The heart of cohomology" by Goro Kato, the Stack Project, Wikipedia), and I have a doubt.

We consider a bigraded cohomological spectral sequence ($E_r^{p,q},\mathrm{d}_r^{p,q}$) in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, with $\mathrm{d}_r^{p,q}:E_r^{p,q}\rightarrow E_r^{p+r,q-r+1}$.
We can define the objects $B^sE_r^{p,q}$ and $Z^{s}E_r^{p,q}$, in such a way that we have

$
0=B^0E_r^{p,q}\subseteq B^1E_r^{p,q}\subseteq\dots\subseteq B^sE_r^{p,q}\subseteq\dots\subseteq Z^sE_r^{p,q}\subseteq\dots\subseteq Z^1E_r^{p,q}\subseteq Z^0E_r^{p,q}=E_r^{p,q}.
$

Now, if they exist (for example if $\mathcal{A}$ ha countable products and coproducts), we can define the objects $B^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}=\mathrm{colim}B^sE_r^{p,q}$ and $Z^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}=\mathrm{lim}Z^sE_r^{p,q}$. These are filtered co/limits, and they are usually written as $B^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}=\bigcup B^sE_r^{p,q}$ and $Z^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}=\bigcap Z^sE_r^{p,q}$, since they indeed have this form in the case of $\mathcal{A}$ being a category of modules or other similar "concrete" categories.

By the various universal properties involved, we have a morphism $j_r^{p,q}:B^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}\rightarrow Z^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}$, and we can then set $E_{\infty}^{p,q}=\mathrm{Coker}j_r^{p,q}$ (one should then verify that this is "independent on r", i.e. all these objects are isomorphic).

The authors, though, write this as $E_{\infty}^{p,q}=\frac{Z^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}}{B^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}}$, and so they are implicitly assuming that $j_r^{p,q}$ is injective. Though I can clearly see this is true in some concrete examples (e.g. if $\mathcal{A}$ is a category of modules), I don't see if and why this is true in general, since in general taking colimits is not an exact operation.

So, my question is, is it always true that $j_r^{p,q}:B^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}\rightarrow Z^{\infty}E_r^{p,q}$ is always injective?

Comment: Limits preserve kernels, filtered colimits do too. No?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2150/exactness-of-filtered-colimits This link shows there are counterexamples to the commutativity of filtered colimits and finite limits in some abelian categories.

Comment: I am not talking about commuting anything, or do you mean exactness ? In that case, I suppose what I want to say is, you first take the limit of the injections from $B$ to $Z$ to get a diagram from many $B$ to $\lim Z$, this is always injective because limits are left exact. Then, you take the filtered colimit of these injections to get $\operatorname{colim} B\to \lim Z$, which will be injective if your filtered colimits are exact. I don't understand what category you have in mind, though. Do you want to compute with spectral sequences in pathological Abelian categories, or...?

Comment: Yes, I mean exacteness. I guess my question should be  whether   in order to deduce the injectivity we should assume an additional axiom (I just found that the exactness of filtered colimits+cocompleteness of $\mathcal{A}$ is called axiom AB5:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AB5_category).  I also wonder if the subsequent theory depends on this assumption, or not.

Comment: For the "usual argument" to go through you probably need them. I still don't understand *why* you want to look at spectral sequences in pathological Abelian categories, though.

Comment: There's no particular reason, it's more a curiosity of mine than anything. The fact is that in every exposition I'm reading it is tacitly assumed that the category $\mathcal{A}$ is "good" enough, but it is never stated clearly. I obviously understand that the most interesting cases occur in such nice categories.